# What is the probability that a five card poker hand contains at most 1 ace?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

What is the probability that a five card poker hand contains at most 1 ace?

I know that if it is at least $1$: 
$$\frac{C(4,1) \cdot C(51,4)}{C(52,5)}$$
I also know that if it is exactly $1$, then it is: 
$$\frac{C(4,1) \cdot C(48,4)}{C(52,5)}$$
What would at most be:
$$1 - \frac{C(4,1) \cdot C(51,4)}{C(52,5)}$$ 
and if so what is non complement representation?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I think your first expression (for at least one Ace) is wrong. How did you calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

If a hand has at most one ace, it has either no aces or one ace.

The number of five-card hands with no aces is 
$$\binom{4}{0}\binom{48}{5} = \binom{48}{5}$$
since all five cards must be chosen from the $52 - 4 = 48$ cards that are not aces.

The number of five-card hands with exactly one ace is 
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4}$$
since one of the four aces and four of the other $48$ cards in the deck must be selected.

Since there are 
$$\binom{52}{5}$$
possible five-card hands, the probability of selecting at most one ace is 
$$\Pr(\text{at most one ace}) = \frac{\dbinom{48}{5} + \dbinom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4}}{\dbinom{52}{5}}$$

*What errors did you make?*

The number of hands with at least one ace is found by subtracting the number of hands with no aces from the total number of hands, which is 
$$\binom{52}{5} - \binom{48}{5}$$
Alternatively, you could add the number of hands with exactly $k$ aces, where $1 \leq k \leq 5$.
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{4} \binom{4}{k}\binom{48}{5 - k} = \binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{3} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{2} + \binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{1}$$

Also, at most $1$ is the complement of at least $2$.